# Not able to get date value on other step in multistep form

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have multistep form of 3 steps.On 2 step in have date input box.I want to get date value on third step but it is showing error.

```
  <input type="date" name="date" id="date" min="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>" class="datepicker" id="datepicker" />

 <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" name="nextnew" id="nextnew" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
```

This is my date input box and I have 2 button to go to the next step and previou step.

```
<?php

 $query5=mysql_query("select * from doctorbooking where aday='".$_REQUEST['date']."'");

 $query6=mysql_fetch_array($query5);

?>
```

I want to retrive value from database table name "doctorbooking" on date value by selecting date in second step but it is showing error.(Undefined index: date)
This is my js.

```
   <script>
     //jQuery time
     var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
    var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
     var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

      $(".next").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
animating = true;

current_fs = $(this).parent();
next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

//activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
$("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

//show the next fieldset
next_fs.show(); 
//hide the current fieldset with style
current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
        //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
        //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
        scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
        //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
        left = (now * 50)+"%";
        //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
        opacity = 1 - now;
        current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'});
        next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
    }, 
    duration: 800, 
    complete: function(){
        current_fs.hide();
        animating = false;
    }, 
    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
 });

   $(".previous").click(function(){
if(animating) return false;
animating = true;

current_fs = $(this).parent();
previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

//de-activate current step on progressbar
$("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

//show the previous fieldset
previous_fs.show(); 
//hide the current fieldset with style
current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
        //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
        //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
        scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
        //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
        left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
        //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
        opacity = 1 - now;
        current_fs.css({'left': left});
        previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
    }, 
    duration: 800, 
    complete: function(){
        current_fs.hide();
        animating = false;
    }, 
    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
});
});

  $(".submit").click(function(){
   return false;
  })

 </script>
```

Comment: FYI...The date `input`-tag should be a self closing tag, just like your button inputs...

Comment: <input type="date" name="date" id="date" min="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>" class="datepicker" id="datepicker" /> i have changed but it is not working.

Comment: How do you go from page to page? Are you posting forms in each step? Using JS? We need to see more of your forms to be able to understand _how_ you are passing the values etc...

Comment: I have used js.

Comment: I have updated my question @ Magnus Eriksson.

Comment: We need to see all that, other wise we're just guessing here... your above code, apart from using the deprecated `mysql_*`-functions and being totally open to SQL Injection attacks, isn't the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123664/discussion-between-rahul-pamnani-and-magnus-eriksson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `POST` or `GET` instead of Request

```
<?php

 $query5=mysql_query("select * from doctorbooking where aday='".$_POST['date']."'");

 $query6=mysql_fetch_array($query5);

?>
```

Comment: Not Working @Gulmuhammad Akbari

Comment: I have multistep form.In second step I have date input box and in third step i want the value of date input box.

Comment: No, the problem is with your php code not in html tags

Comment: Explain please.

Comment: if i will change the type from button to submit it won't go to the next step.

Comment: According the error "Undefined index: date" it means the date field not recognized with request.

Comment: When you declare input type button or submit, the form submits automatically.

Comment: I have submit button on third step.<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="action-button" value="Submit" style="width: 100px;background-color: #27AE60;color: white;padding: 10px 5px;
    margin: 10px 5px;" />

Comment: I think you're forms are messed up. Can you show us the complete form? Are you using js on button click events? If so, we would need to see that too. (update your question).